Error import markdown files in Astro using Astro.glob()
I was trying to import some markdown files in Astro in order to make a "dynamic" blog. I used Astro.glob(). I already had it functioning perfectly. However, since a recent update it stopped working.
The code:
---
let posts: any[];
try {
    posts = await Astro.glob("./blog/*.md");
    console.log(posts.length);
    posts = shuffleArray(posts);
    posts = posts.slice(0, 15);
} catch (error) {
    posts = [];
    console.log(error);
}
---

The file structure is: project_root/pages/blog/*.md
This is the layout of the blog posts:
import shuffleArray from "../helpers/shuffleArray";
import MenuLayout from "./MenuLayout.astro";
const { frontmatter } = Astro.props;

let posts;
try {
    posts = await Astro.glob("*.md");
    posts = shuffleArray(posts);
    let i;
    for(i = 0; i < posts.length - 2; i++) {
        if (posts[i].url === Astro.url.pathname 
          || posts[i + 1].url === Astro.url.pathname
          || posts[i + 2].url === Astro.url.pathname) {
          continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    posts = posts.slice(i, i + 2);
} catch (error) {
    posts = "";
}




<MenuLayout title={frontmatter.title}>
    <main>
        <article id="central">
        <slot />
        </article>
    </main>
</MenyLayout>

This is the markdown header example:
---
layout: ../../layouts/BlogPostLayout.astro
title: Something
author: something
img_url: /obiwan.gif
date: 2024-05-29
---

I tried changing the routes, the directory name or the files extension. This only happens to me when it's the .md extension. I tried with .astro and it works just right.
The problem really is that is just want to import it access them and pass the data of the URL to a component to just generate the routes.
EDIT: error message
Error: Invalid glob: "*.md" (resolved: "*.md"). It must start with '/' or './'
    at toAbsoluteGlob (file:///home/kinire98/Documents/portfolio/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-DyBnyoVI.js:39014:9)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async file:///home/kinire98/Documents/portfolio/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-DyBnyoVI.js:38843:27
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async parseImportGlob (file:///home/kinire98/Documents/portfolio/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-DyBnyoVI.js:38857:11)
    at async transformGlobImport (file:///home/kinire98/Documents/portfolio/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-DyBnyoVI.js:38888:19)
    at async TransformPluginContext.transform (file:///home/kinire98/Documents/portfolio/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-DyBnyoVI.js:38662:22)
    at async PluginContainer.transform (file:///home/kinire98/Documents/portfolio/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-DyBnyoVI.js:49033:18)
    at async loadAndTransform (file:///home/kinire98/Documents/portfolio/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-DyBnyoVI.js:51866:27)


Astro.glob is a thin wrapper around vite's import.meta.glob, and as such does weird things at build-time. But maybe try that instead? or follow https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/markdown-content/ more closely?

I'll look into import.meta.glob. But I followed very closely the Astro docs. Maybe I'll give another try

The problem was that the glob was invalid. Not the one I thought, but other in the codebase.
Search for other globs in your code base.
Answering for anyone out there that needs this.
Astro.glob() itself isn't broken, which is what I thought previously

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
